# switch between layouts in flex4

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, tile, effect

i have the list shown below with 2 layouts between which i switch:

```
<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{ recordingsShown }"
                itemRenderer.CoverflowState="components.VideoItemRenderer" 
                itemRenderer.TileState="components.VideoItemRenderer2"
                selectedIndex="0">

 <s:layout.CoverflowState>
    <Layouts:CoverflowLayout id="coverflow" selectedIndex="{ list.selectedIndex }"
                                         horizontalDistance="103" selectedItemProximity="75"
                                         depthDistance="1" elementRotation="-70" focalLength="300"
                                         perspectiveProjectionX="-1" perspectiveProjectionY="-1"/>
 </s:layout.CoverflowState>

 <s:layout.TileState>

    <s:TileLayout orientation="columns" columnAlign="justifyUsingWidth" rowAlign="justifyUsingHeight"
                              requestedColumnCount="-1"
                              requestedRowCount="-1"
                              paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5"
                              verticalGap="10" horizontalGap="10"/>

 </s:layout.TileState>
</s:List>
```

1) The problem is that i get

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

at Layouts::CoverflowLayout/animationTickHandler()[line:201]

at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()

at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

when i switch from coverflow to tilelayout and i think its because the effect used in the coverflow has not ended and i switch to the other layout,any help?.

[Coverflow layout used](http://www.rialvalue.com/blog/2010/03/30/flex4-coverflow-layout/comment-page-1/#comment-18080)

2) how can i use any transition effect between them so as to be more "sweet" the switch between them!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that some parts inside the list aren't created yet.

When you using states, by default, the components are created on the first switch to this state

Try to play around with the creation policy [adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ddd)